# trouble creating a stored procedure to print out values for each day of week

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am having difficulty in understanding how to get this working correctly. I am trying to create a stored procedure that is run automatically on a Sunday. It will get the data for the previous week. On executing this stored procedure there are conversion issues from int to nvarchar but I can't understand where this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
USE be_crm4_MSCRM;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getKeypadSwitchoversInPreviousWeek 
AS 

declare @Monday int, 
@Tuesday int,
@Wednesday int,
@Thursday int,
@Friday int,
@Saturday int

SET NOCOUNT ON;
set @Monday = (select count(*) as '08/06/2015' from AccountExtensionBase
where CAST(DATEADD(hour,1,new_golivedate) as date) = CAST(DATEADD(day,-6,GETDATE()) as date)
and New_AccountType = 5);

set @Tuesday = (select count(*) as '09/06/2015' from AccountExtensionBase
where CAST(DATEADD(hour,1,new_golivedate) as date) = CAST(DATEADD(day,-5,GETDATE()) as date)
and New_AccountType = 5);

set @Wednesday = (select count(*) as '10/06/2015' from AccountExtensionBase
where CAST(DATEADD(hour,1,new_golivedate) as date) = CAST(DATEADD(day,-4,GETDATE()) as date)
and New_AccountType = 5);

set @Thursday = (select count(*) as '11/06/2015' from AccountExtensionBase
where CAST(DATEADD(hour,1,new_golivedate) as date) = CAST(DATEADD(day,-3,GETDATE()) as date)
and New_AccountType = 5);

set @Friday = (select count(*) as '12/06/2015' from AccountExtensionBase
where CAST(DATEADD(hour,1,new_golivedate) as date) = CAST(DATEADD(day,-2,GETDATE()) as date)
and New_AccountType = 5);

set @Saturday = (select count(*) as '13/06/2015' from AccountExtensionBase
where CAST(DATEADD(hour,1,new_golivedate) as date) = CAST(DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()) as date)
and New_AccountType = 5);

print N'Monday = ' + @Monday;
print N'Tuesday = ' + @Tuesday;
print N'Wednesday = ' + @Wednesday;
print N'Thursday = ' + @Thursday;
print N'Friday = ' + @Friday;
print N'Saturday = ' + @Saturday;
```

GO

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to concat an int to a string in the print statements.

```
print N'Monday = ' + @Monday;
```

If you're desired output is Monday = 123 as a string, the @Monday variable will need to be converted to a string type, like so:

```
print N'Monday = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),@Monday);
```

There is also no need for the alias column in your selects if you are returning only the count to each variable.

Answer (score 0):

As @jspaeth answered, the conversion issue is in your print statement.

However, I couldn't let this go without offering some tuning advice for you.  I would suggest making this a single query as I've outlined below instead of 6 distinct reads on the same base table.  Depending on how many rows you have, this could save you quite a bit of time.  You may need to tweak the query below a bit but should set you on the correct track.

```
DECLARE @AEB TABLE
    (
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , New_AccountType INT NOT NULL
    , new_golivedate DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL
    )

INSERT INTO @AEB
    (New_AccountType, new_golivedate)
VALUES (5, DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()))
    , (5, DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()))
    , (5, DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE()))
    , (5, DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE()))
    , (5, DATEADD(DAY, -6, GETDATE()))
    , (5, DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()))
    , (5, DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE()))

DECLARE @Monday INT
DECLARE @Tuesday INT
DECLARE @Wednesday INT
DECLARE @Thursday INT
DECLARE @Friday INT
DECLARE @Saturday INT

;WITH CTE_Account AS
    (
    SELECT ActivityDaysAgo = DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), CAST(DATEADD(hour,1,new_golivedate) as date))
        , COUNT(ID) AS AccountCount
    FROM @AEB AS A
    WHERE New_AccountType = 5
        AND CAST(DATEADD(hour,1,new_golivedate) as date) BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -6, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AND CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
    GROUP BY CAST(DATEADD(hour,1,new_golivedate) as date)
    )
SELECT @Monday = COALESCE(P.[-1], 0)
    , @Tuesday = COALESCE(P.[-2], 0)
    , @Wednesday = COALESCE(P.[-3], 0)
    , @Thursday = COALESCE(P.[-4], 0)
    , @Friday = COALESCE(P.[-5], 0)
    , @Saturday = COALESCE(P.[-6], 0)
FROM CTE_Account
    PIVOT (SUM(AccountCount) FOR ActivityDaysAgo IN ([-1], [-2], [-3], [-4], [-5], [-6])) AS P

print N'Monday = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Monday);
print N'Tuesday = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Tuesday);
print N'Wednesday = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Wednesday);
print N'Thursday = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Thursday);
print N'Friday = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Friday);
print N'Saturday = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Saturday);
```